# Как отсортировать граничные элементы матрицы по возрастанию методом слияния?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void printMatrix(int grid[][5], int m, int n)
{
vector<int> A;

 
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
    if (j == n - 1 || (i == m - 1) || j == 0
        || i == 0)
        A.push_back(grid[i][j]);
    }
}

 
sort(A.begin(), A.end());

// Printing first row with
// first N elements from A
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << A[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
 

 
for (int i = 0; i < m - 2; i++)
{
 
    cout << A[A.size() - i - 1] << " ";

     
 
    for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++)
    cout << grid[i + 1][j] << " ";

     
    cout << (A[n + i]) << endl;
}

 
reverse(A.begin() + n + m - 2,
        A.begin() + n + m + n - 2);
for (int i = n + m - 2; i < n + m - 2 + n; i++)
    cout << A[i] << " ";
 
}

 
int main()
{
// Dimensions of a Matrix
int m = 4, n = 5;

 
int grid[][5] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 },
                { 1, 2, 2, 2, 4 },
                { 1, 9, 3, 1, 7 } };

 
printMatrix(grid, m, n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что не получается? Вы же граничные элементы скопировали в вектор, отсортировали (правда быстрой сортировкой). Теперь верните их в матрицу в том порядке, как нужно.

Comment: Мне нужно  методом слияния

Comment: Ну так посмотрите как работает сортировка слиянием и напишите! https://academy.yandex.ru/posts/osnovnye-vidy-sortirovok-i-primery-ikh-realizatsii